# Wrap every nth piece of content with 2 divs in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, carousel

I am trying to wrap two divs around every 3 pieces of content generated from an API call.  It should look like this:

```
 <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item carousel-item">
           <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                     <div class="thumb-wrapper">
                          Content Here (1)              
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                     <div class="thumb-wrapper">
                          Content Here (2)              
                     </div>
                </div>          
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                     <div class="thumb-wrapper">
                          Content Here (3)              
                     </div>
                </div>
           </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item carousel-item">
           <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                     <div class="thumb-wrapper">
                          Content Here (4)              
                     </div>
                </div>
           </div>
      </div>
 </div>
```

I have worked on this all day and I can't seem to get it right.  Also, I may not be using the most efficient method.  I am hoping that someone can tell me what I am doing wrong and how to fix it... also, I am open to any advice as far as streamlining my code.  So, with this search 4 pieces of content are returned, and every set of 3 should be wrapped in two divs (item carousel-item and row), but in my attempt below, it seems to be wrapping correctly, but it surrounds 4 instead of three and then brings back a duplicate piece of content for the 4th, I also have an extra div at the end...  yikes :)

What I have it doing so far:

```
 <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item carousel-item">
           <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                     <div class="thumb-wrapper">
                          Content Here (1)
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                     <div class="thumb-wrapper">
                          <div class="img-box">
                               Content Here (2)
                          </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                     <div class="thumb-wrapper">
                          <div class="img-box">
                               Content Here (3)
                          </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
                ***this div should not be here, should have stopped at 3***
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                     <div class="thumb-wrapper">
                          <div class="img-box">
                               Content Here (4)
                          </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
           </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item carousel-item">
           <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                     <div class="thumb-wrapper">
                          <div class="img-box">
                               Content Here (4)
                          </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
           </div>
      </div>
 </div>
 ***extra div shows up at end***
 </div>
```

Here is the code I used:

```
 jQuery.each(ws_ftr, function(index, ftr) {
           if(index % 3 === 0){
                jQuery('.carousel-inner').append('<div class="item carousel-item active"><div class="row">');
           }
           jQuery('.row').append('<div class="col-sm-4"><div class="thumb-wrapper"><div class="img-box">Content Here</div></div></div>');
           if(index % 3 === 0){
                jQuery('.row').append('</div></div>');
           }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code should be like

```
function createColumnsList(arr) {
  var html = '<div class="row">'; 
  //or another code to start your row like $.append or smth
  $.each(arr, function(index, item) {
    if (index % 3 == 0 && index != 0) {
      html += '</div><div class="row">'; 
     //end and start your row
    }
    html += '<div class="column">' + item + '</div>'; 
    // output your content from array
  });
  html += "</div>"; 
  //end row
  return html;
}
```

Change it to fit your needs. Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Thank you for sharing this solution.  Honestly, I couldn't get it to work because I am still pretty new to javascript and I just didn't know how... but I was able to use your code to figure out another way (without the function) and it works great!  So thank you so much.  One day, when I am better at this I will look back at this post and laugh (hopefully) at whatever is is that I don't know now :)

Comment: Np, bro:) It's just an example of method how to solve your problem. I'm glad that you made your code work:) 
Good luck and don't hesitate to ask something here :)